# How to alter data in a XML file from a webpage using AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm new if it comes to using AJAX in combination with XML files. I'm stuck for two days and can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

I'm making a quiz-game where a monitor is used to display players, questions and answers. I want the players to be able to use their phones to connect to the specific 'game session' and thus alter data that is stored in the XML file corresponding to this game.

What I have my until so far, is a function that fetches the data from the XML file, and checks for changes in this file every 500ms so it can update the corresponding content on the 'main screen'. In short: I know how to display the data from the XML.

My problem is: how can I make a player alter the existing data or add data in the XML file? For example, player enters the input fields (name and age) and this gets added to the XML File.

I hope somebody can help me!

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="mainMenuBlock">

        <form action="">
            <label for="playerName">Name:</label>
            <input id="playerName" name="playerName" type="text">

            <label for="playerName">Age:</label>
            <input id="playerAge" name="playerAge" type="number">

            <button type="submit">Add player</button>
        </form>

        <ul id="playerList"></ul>
    
    </div>
</body>
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<game_data>

    <player>
        <name>Sjoerd</name>
        <age>9</age>
    </player>

    <player>
        <name>Melanie</name>
        <age>23</age>
    </player>

    <player>
        <name>Remco</name>
        <age>27</age>
    </player>

    <player>
        <name>Ilse</name>
        <age>23</age>
    </player>

</game_data>
```

jQuery/AJAX call (to fetch the data  and update/display the list on the HTML page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  fetchData();
});

function fetchData() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    showPlayers();
    fetchData();
  }, 500);
}

function showPlayers() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:8848/lib/data/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",

    error: function (e) {
      alert("An error occurred while processing XML file");
      console.log("XML reading Failed: ", e);
    },

    success: function (response) {
      $("ul").children().remove();

      $(response)
        .find("player")
        .each(function () {
          var _name = "Name: " + $(this).find("name").text();
          var _age = "Age: " + $(this).find("age").text();

          $("ul").append("<li>" + _name + "</li>");
          $("ul").append("<li>" + _age + "</li>");
        });
    },
  });
}
```

[image]